SAP Fiori/sapui5: UploadSet does not work anymore
I experience a strange behaviour. We developed a RAP-App (Fiori Elements) where we enhanced the source code to add a custom button/action to the application. This Action opens a Fragment where you can upload a document.
In the past everything works fine, but since a couple of days it is not working anymore.
The App is deployed as an HTML5-App on our BTP, maybe there was a SAP update and now something behaves differently?! In my BAS it's working.
Here's the code of my Fragment.
<core:FragmentDefinition 
xmlns="sap.m" 
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" 
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified" 
xmlns:upload="sap.m.upload" 
xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" 
xmlns:lab="this.is.my.App.libraries"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:f="sap.f"
xmlns:mdc="sap.ui.mdc"
xmlns:mdct="sap.ui.mdc.table"
xmlns:vm="sap.ui.fl.variants"
xmlns:mdcat="sap.ui.mdc.actiontoolbar">
    <Dialog id="CreateCloseNotificationSet" afterClose="onDialogAfterClose">
        <content>

            <Input id="Equipment" visible="false"/>
            <Label id="lblRequiredStart" labelFor="DateClose" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin"/>
            <DatePicker required="true" id="DateStart" change="handleChange" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom, sapUiTinyMarginBegin" valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" width="99%"/> 

            <Label id="lblRequiredEnd" labelFor="DateClose" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin"/>
            <DatePicker required="true" id="DateEnd" change="handleChange" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom, sapUiTinyMarginBegin" valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" width="99%"/> 

           <Label id="TaskCodes" labelFor="TaskDropdown" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin"/>
            <ComboBox xmlns="sap.m" id="TaskDropdown" width="99%" required="true" items="{listTaskCodes>/}" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom, sapUiTinyMarginBegin">
                <items>
                    <core:Item xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" key="{listTaskCodes>TaskCodeGroup}+{listTaskCodes>TaskCode}" text="{listTaskCodes>ShortText}" id="TextId1"/> 
                </items>
            </ComboBox>
           <Label id="LabelTaskInput" labelFor="TaskInput" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin"/>        
           <Input width="99%" id="TaskInput" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin" maxLength="40"></Input>

           <Label id="ActivityCodes" labelFor="ActivityDropdown" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin"/>
            <ComboBox xmlns="sap.m" id="ActivityDropdown" width="99%" required="true" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom, sapUiTinyMarginBegin" core:require="{ handler: 'this/is/my/App/ext/controller/ExtCustomAction'}" change="handler.onSelectionChange">
                <items>
                    <core:ListItem xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" key="ActivitySuccess" id="ActivitySuccess"/> 
                    <core:ListItem xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" key="ActivityFailure" id="ActivityFailure"/> 
                </items>
            </ComboBox>     
           <Label id="LabelActivityInput" labelFor="ActivityInput" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin"/>        
           <Input width="99%" id="ActivityInput" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin" maxLength="40"></Input>   

            <Label id="lblClosedDate" labelFor="DateClose" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin"/>
            <DatePicker required="true" id="DateClose" change="handleChange" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom, sapUiTinyMarginBegin" valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" width="99%"/>   

           <Label id="LabelCreatedBy" labelFor="CreatedByInput" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin"/>        
           <Input width="99%" id="CreatedByInput" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin" maxLength="12" required="true"></Input>   

            <upload:UploadSet uploadEnabled="true" id="uploadSet" items="{path: '/items', templateShareable: false}" fileTypes="pdf" 
            maxFileNameLength="100" core:require="{ handler: 'this/is/my/App/ext/controller/ExtCustomAction'}" 
            beforeUploadStarts="handler.onBeforeUploadStartCreate" uploadCompleted="handler.onUploadSetCompleteCreate" afterItemRemoved="onItemRemoved" afterItemAdded="handler.onAfterItemAdded"
            terminationEnabled="false"  multiple="true" uploadUrl="/sap/service/I/am/using">
                <upload:UploadSetItem id="uplSetIt" visibleRemove="true" visibleEdit="false" fileName="{name}" url="{url}" mediaType="{mediatype}">
                    <upload:attributes>
                        <ObjectAttribute id="ObjAttr" title="Uploaded by" text="{user}" active="false"/>
                    </upload:attributes>
                </upload:UploadSetItem>
            </upload:UploadSet>        
        </content>
        <buttons>      
            <Button core:require="{ handler: 'this/is/my/App/ext/controller/ExtCustomAction'}"  id="BtnSave"    press="handler.onClose"              icon="sap-icon://save"                  type="Emphasized"/>
            <Button core:require="{ handler: 'this/is/my/App/ext/controller/ExtCustomAction'}"  id="BtnClose"   press="handler.onCloseDialogClose"   icon="sap-icon://close-command-field"/>
        </buttons>  
    </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>

Everything is handled here, my defined methods for uploadCompleted, beforeUploadStartes, etc. are doing nothing. I just put breakpoints there to check and add a csrf-Token in the debugger.
oEvent.getSource().addHeaderField( new sap.ui.core.Item({ key: "x-csrf-token", text: "T0F6GjPdzQzu5koRBvAvLQ==" }))
I also tried deactivating csrfProtection in xs-app.json - without success...
{
  "welcomeFile": "/index.html",
  "authenticationMethod": "route",
  "routes": [
    {
      "source": "^/sap/(.*)$",
      "target": "/sap/$1",
      "destination": "ABAP_Environment",
      "authenticationType": "xsuaa",
      "csrfProtection": false
    },
    {
      "source": "^/resources/(.*)$",
      "target": "/resources/$1",
      "authenticationType": "none",
      "destination": "ui5",
      "csrfProtection": false
    },
    {
      "source": "^/test-resources/(.*)$",
      "target": "/test-resources/$1",
      "authenticationType": "none",
      "destination": "ui5",
      "csrfProtection": false
    },
    {
      "source": "^(.*)$",
      "target": "$1",
      "service": "html5-apps-repo-rt",
      "authenticationType": "xsuaa",
      "csrfProtection": false
    },
    {
      "source": "^(.*?)",
      "target": "(.*?)",
      "service": "html5-apps-repo-rt",
      "authenticationType": "xsuaa",
      "csrfProtection": false
    },
    {
      "source": "^(.*?)",
      "target": "(.*?)",
      "service": "html5-apps-repo",
      "authenticationType": "xsuaa",  
      "csrfProtection": false
    }
  ]
}

Everytime I upload a document I shortly see it in the Upload area, but then it immediately vanishing from the Upload area again.
In the Network Tab I see a 403 Forbidden (POST) that sounds like csrf... But I do not get why it worked the last weeks but not now.
Does anyone of you have an idea?
Every other data fetching and posting within the App works. Does this have anything to to that it's a Fragment?
Thanks in advance,
Julian
I expect, that the uploaded file is shown in the Upload area.
I tried setting csrf-Token in the Debugger.
I tried deactivating csrfProtection in xs-app.json.
I tried different uploadUrls for the uploadSet.
Edit: Added some Information
How does the App behaves?
I can open the Fragment and I see the "UploadSet"-Area where I can press "Upload" or Drag&Drop Documents into.
When I do this a FileDialog is opening where I can chose my document. When I click on "OK" I see the document with the uploading-bar is flashing up
immediately after the document vanished.
Then the UploadSet-Area is empty again and no document is inside.
ConsoleLog
In the Browser console I get the 403 (Forbidden) Error

POST https://.launchpad.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/cp.portal/ui5appruntime.html?siteId=&subaccountId=&saasApprouter=true&sap-ui-app-id=this.is.my.App&scenario=LAUNCHPAD&sap-startup-params=&sap-shell=FLP&sap-touch=0&sap-ui-versionedLibCss=true&sap-plugins=RTAPluginAgent&sap-history-dir=NewEntry&sap-personalization=false&sap-theme=CustomTheme@https://.launchpad.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/comsapuitheming.runtime/themeroot/v1/~v=Base:11.19.0,..CustomTheme(sap_horizon):20240325T134134Z&sap-locale=de-DE&sap-propagate-async-loading=true&sap-iframe-hint=UI5&sap-spaces=true 403 (Forbidden)

Versions
My Fiori Workzone shows Framework-ID = UI5; Framework-Version = 1.129.2 (202410091142); Source System = saas_approuter
In my Preview from BAS I see
Framework-Version = 1.117.4 (202311091704)

Could you elaborate more on what exactly is not working? Is the dialog not opening? Is there any relevant error in the browser console? Which UI5 versions are the deployed app and the app preview from BAS using?

Sure, I edited my original Post

Try using the same SAPUI5 version for the BAS preview and see if the issue is still not there. If so, create an SAP Support ticket.
